# Добавляются кавычки в CSV PHP

Tags: php, csv

Подскажите почему при экспорте на PHP в мой файл попадают кавычки?
Сам массив через var_dump()

```
array(3) {
[0]=> array(6) { 
    ["id"]=> string(2) "ID" 
    ["name"]=> string(24) "Наименование" 
    ["price"]=> string(8) "Цена" 
    ["category"]=> string(18) "Категория" 
    ["store"]=> string(14) "Магазин" 
    ["currency"]=> string(12) "Валюта" 
} 
[1]=> array(6) { 
    ["id"]=> int(1) 
    ["name"]=> string(67) "Аккумулятор Samsung A7 2015 SM-A700 GH43-04340B ORIG100%" 
    ["price"]=> string(4) "1100" 
    ["category"]=> string(16) "Запчасти" 
    ["store"]=> string(14) "RestartService" 
    ["currency"]=> string(3) "RUB" 
} 
[2]=> array(6) { 
    ["id"]=> int(2) 
    ["name"]=> string(67) "Аккумулятор Samsung A5 2015 SM-A500 GH43-04337A ORIG100%" 
    ["price"]=> string(4) "1100" 
    ["category"]=> string(16) "Запчасти" 
    ["store"]=> string(14) "RestartService" 
    ["currency"]=> string(3) "RUB" 
}
}
```

Данные которые записываются в CSV

```
ID,Наименование,Цена,Категория,Магазин,Валюта
1,"Аккумулятор Samsung A7 2015 SM-A700 GH43-04340B ORIG100%",1100,Запчасти,RestartService,RUB
2,"Аккумулятор Samsung A5 2015 SM-A500 GH43-04337A ORIG100%",1100,Запчасти,RestartService,RUB
```

При том в колонки наименования кавычки отсутвуют

```
public function getCSV() {
    $fp = fopen('farpost_price.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($this->generateData() as $fields) {

        fputcsv($fp, $fields, ',');

    }

    var_dump($this->generateData());

    fclose($fp);
}
public function generateData() {

    $id = 0;
    //Проходим циклом по ссылкам продавцов
    foreach ($this->store as $key => $item) {
        //Получаем кол-во страниц
        $countPage = $this->countPage($item);
        //Проходим циклам по страницам
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $countPage; $i++) {
            //Получаем страницу
            $page = new HtmlPage(file_get_contents($item . $i), '', 'windows-1251');
            //Фильтруем текущию страницу
            $page->filter('tr.bull-item');

            //Проходим циклом по самой странице
            foreach ($page->filter('tr.bull-item') as $val) {
                $val = new HtmlPageCrawler($val);


                $this->product[] = [
                    'id' => ++$id,
                    //'name' => $this->substrName($val->filter('a.bulletinLink')->text()),
                    'name' => $val->filter('a.bulletinLink')->text(),
                    'price' => $this->priceReplace($val->filter('.priceCell')->text()),
                    'category' => 'Запчасти',
                    'store' => $key,
                    'currency' => 'RUB',
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->product;
}
```

так же побывал удалять кавычки перед записью в файл но их там НЕТ! Судя из var_dump() да и пошагова код смотрел визде их нет. Мне кажется что как то это связанно с типами данных но ответа  так и не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP добавляет кавычки, чтобы не было проблем с символами, совпадающими с разделителем значений в csv. В этом нет ничего страшного, это все еще валидный csv.

Но если все же надо без ковычек, то вместо fputcsv можно использовать fwrite

```
fwrite($fp, implode(',', $fields) . "\r\n");
```

Comment: Спасибо дружище! Работает. Странная эта штука CSV)))